# Python complicated dictionary sorting

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary, of which every key is holding a list as a value. Each list has one or more tuples with 2 items inside, one integer, one string.

Example:

```
my_dict = {'dict_key_1': [(100, 'string_x1234'), (95, 'string_rtx3') ..],
           'dict_key_2': [(26, 'string_abc3'), (321, 'string_432fd'), ...],
           'dict_key_3': [(32, 'string_232df']}
```

I am iterating through this dictionary, and whilst doing that through items in the list.

However, in both iterations I must have the dictionary sorted by the highest value of the first item of any tuple in the list.

So in that case, since **321** is highest, I would get **dict_key_2** first, and its items would be listed starting with the tuple of which first item is **321**, then **26** and so on.

I am fine with the second iteration (sorting the list of tuples) with:

```
sorted(data[k], reverse = True)
```

But I currently fail at sorting the main dictionary depending on the highest value of any tuple in the list that that key of dictionary is holding. I currently have:

```
for k in sorted(data, key=lambda k: sorted(data[k])[0][0]):
```

However, it is not working. But when I try to print `sorted(data[k])[0][0])` whilst iterating, it does indeed give the first value [0] of first tuple [0] after having it ordered on the first values of all tuples in that list (`data[k]`)

What am I doing wrong? How can I get this dictionary sorted as needed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind sorting the lists in your dict, I would recommend to do this in two passes:

```
for L in my_dict.itervalues():
  L.sort(reverse=True)

import collections
my_sorted_dict = collections.OrderedDict((k, my_dict[k]) for k in sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get, reverse=True))
```

Comment: Easier (and more efficient) to use: `OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))`

Answer (score 1):

Use `max`:

```
for k in sorted(data, key=lambda k: max(data[k]), reverse=True):
```

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet will give you a new sorted dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

my_dict = {'dict_key_1': [(100, 'string_x1234'), (95, 'string_rtx3')],
           'dict_key_2': [(26, 'string_abc3'), (321, 'string_432fd')],
           'dict_key_3': [(32, 'string_232df')]}

sorted_my_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.iteritems(),
                                    key=lambda (k, v): max(v),
                                    reverse=True))
```

Comment: My bad, I just forgot to use OrderedDict.